How to show assets of a local package in Flutter
I have a parent project and a local subproject that has been added to the parent project like this
- parent
  - packages/subproject

this subproject has some assets inside it that have been added like this
- packages/subproject/lib/assets/icons

and this is subproject pubspec.yaml
assets:
  - packages/messaging_core/assets/icons/

and I also call the icons like this path
packages/messaging_core/assets/icons/copy.svg

but I cant see the icons in local package in my app
however if I send this to github and import it from there everything would be fine.
any idea what is wrong?

The issue might be related to the path you're using in your pubspec.yaml file. When referencing assets from a local package, you should use the lib/ prefix instead of packages/.
Try changing your asset declaration in your subproject's pubspec.yaml file like this:
assets:
  - lib/assets/icons/

Then, when you want to access these assets in your code, you should use the package: scheme followed by the package name and the path to the asset:
Image.asset('package:messaging_core/assets/icons/copy.svg')

or
Image.asset('package/messaging_core/assets/icons/copy.svg')

Also, make sure that you've added the local package to your parent project's pubspec.yaml under dependencies like this:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  messaging_core:
    path: packages/messaging_core

Lastly, don't forget to run flutter pub get after modifying your pubspec.yaml files.
